# Failing to use get_accName for MFC control

Tags: c++, mfc, accessibility

I have an MFC control. I want the items in it to have distinct names in tools such as AccExplorer. I call `EnableActiveAccessibility` in the constructor and I have attempted to overload `get_accName` as follows:

```
HRESULT CGPP2XDCAMPathAndDesc::get_accName(VARIANT varChild, BSTR * pszName)
{
HRESULT res = S_OK;
if (varChild.vt != VT_I4)
{
    *pszName = NULL;
    return E_INVALIDARG;
}
switch (varChild.lVal) 
{
case CHILDID_SELF:
    *pszName = SysAllocString(_T("P2XDCAM control"));
    break;
case CHILDID_DRIVE_LIST:
    *pszName = SysAllocString(_T("Path list"));
    break;
...
default:
    res = E_UNEXPECTED;
    break;
};

return res;
}
```

When I attempt to get the accessible data of the control in its entirety, I get this: [image: AccExplorer where the root control is P2XDCAM, all its child controls are marked "Not initialized!"] 
Clicking any of the "not initialized" controls on AccExplorer doesn't select the control itself.

Whereas if I click the individual controls within the control, I get this:
[image]

Any idea how to make this work?